# How do I increase the upload size using WebHDFS (Cloudera)?

Tags: java, hadoop, cloudera, webhdfs

I'm attempting to create an ~80mb file in Hadoop using WebHDFS with op=CREATE.  This works fine for small files, but with the 80mb files I get an exception with:

```
Form too large9000000>20000
```

I realize I could probably chunk this, but 20k seems like a pretty tiny chunk. Is there a way I configure Hadoop, Cloudera specifically, to allow me to upload larger chunks and files?

Thanks!

Comment: Please go through this URL, are you using this. ? which version of hadoop is being used https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#Create_and_Write_to_a_File

Comment: I'm using 2.6.0-cdh5.15.0.  I have been looking at that page, and I'm using that API.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding the blocksize argument.  I thought blocksize was an internal HDFS setting, and generally 128mb by default. I'm a bit of a newbie to HDFS.